# How to scroll inside DIV using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium, scroll, webdriver

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fQZn.png)

In DIV only five element will be shown at a time and HTML code will also have only five tgas as below.

```
<div class="filter-item-wrapper" style="width: 193px; height: 150.5px; overflow: hidden;">
<div class="filter-item" style="padding-top: 4.625px; padding-bottom: 4.625px; border-width: 1px; margin: 2px; height: 20px; box-sizing: content-box; width: 322px; display: block; left: 0px;">
<div class="filter-item" style="padding-top: 4.625px; padding-bottom: 4.625px; border-width: 1px; margin: 2px; height: 20px; box-sizing: content-box; width: 322px; display: block; left: 0px;">
<div class="filter-item" style="padding-top: 4.625px; padding-bottom: 4.625px; border-width: 1px; margin: 2px; height: 20px; box-sizing: content-box; width: 322px; display: block; left: 0px;">
<div class="filter-item" style="padding-top: 4.625px; padding-bottom: 4.625px; border-width: 1px; margin: 2px; height: 20px; box-sizing: content-box; width: 322px; display: block; left: 0px;">
<div class="filter-item" style="padding-top: 4.625px; padding-bottom: 4.625px; border-width: 1px; margin: 2px; height: 20px; box-sizing: content-box; width: 322px; display: block; left: 0px;">
</div>
```

On scrolling down only above five elements data will be refreshed.

I tried using below code.

```
// Create instance of Javascript executor
JavascriptExecutor je = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
//Identify the WebElement which will appear after scrolling down
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.tagName("...."));
// now execute query which actually will scroll until that element is not appeared on page.
je.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",element);
```

but this won't help me as every time last element is same only data inside element gets refreshed.

Please help me how to scroll in above list.

Before Scroll

```
<div class="filter-item-wrapper" style="width: 193px; height: 150.5px; overflow: hidden;">
<div class="filter-item" style="padding-top: 4.625px; padding-bottom: 4.625px; border-width: 1px; margin: 2px; height: 20px; box-sizing: content-box; width: 322px;">
<input class="filter-item-input" value="(Blanks)" type="checkbox">
<span class="filter-item-text">(Blanks)</span>
</div>
<div class="filter-item" style="padding-top: 4.625px; padding-bottom: 4.625px; border-width: 1px; margin: 2px; height: 20px; box-sizing: content-box; width: 322px;">
<input class="filter-item-input" value="BMC Remedy Migrator 3.0" type="checkbox">
<span class="filter-item-text">BMC Remedy Migrator 3.0</span>
</div>
<div class="filter-item" style="padding-top: 4.625px; padding-bottom: 4.625px; border-width: 1px; margin: 2px; height: 20px; box-sizing: content-box; width: 322px;">
<input class="filter-item-input" value="Bottomline Create!form Director 6.1" type="checkbox">
<span class="filter-item-text">Bottomline Create!form Director 6.1</span>
</div>
<div class="filter-item" style="padding-top: 4.625px; padding-bottom: 4.625px; border-width: 1px; margin: 2px; height: 20px; box-sizing: content-box; width: 322px;">
<input class="filter-item-input" value="Bottomline Create!form Director 6.2" type="checkbox">
<span class="filter-item-text">Bottomline Create!form Director 6.2</span>
</div>
<div class="filter-item" style="padding-top: 4.625px; padding-bottom: 4.625px; border-width: 1px; margin: 2px; height: 20px; box-sizing: content-box; width: 322px;">
<input class="filter-item-input" value="Cisco Application Networking Manager (ANM) 4.1" type="checkbox">
<span class="filter-item-text">Cisco Application Networking Manager (ANM) 4.1</span>
</div>
</div>
```

After Scroll

```
<div class="filter-item-wrapper" style="width: 193px; height: 150.5px; overflow: hidden;">
<div class="filter-item" style="padding-top: 4.625px; padding-bottom: 4.625px; border-width: 1px; margin: 2px; height: 20px; box-sizing: content-box; width: 344px;">
<input class="filter-item-input" value="Sage Peachtree Premium Accounting 12.0 SR2 (2005)" type="checkbox">
<span class="filter-item-text">Sage Peachtree Premium Accounting 12.0 SR2 (2005)</span>
</div>
<div class="filter-item" style="padding-top: 4.625px; padding-bottom: 4.625px; border-width: 1px; margin: 2px; height: 20px; box-sizing: content-box; width: 344px;">
<input class="filter-item-input" value="Sage Peachtree Premium Accounting 12.0 SR3 (2005)" type="checkbox">
<span class="filter-item-text">Sage Peachtree Premium Accounting 12.0 SR3 (2005)</span>
</div>
<div class="filter-item" style="padding-top: 4.625px; padding-bottom: 4.625px; border-width: 1px; margin: 2px; height: 20px; box-sizing: content-box; width: 344px;">
<input class="filter-item-input" value="Sage Peachtree Premium Accounting 13.0 (2006)" type="checkbox">
<span class="filter-item-text">Sage Peachtree Premium Accounting 13.0 (2006)</span>
</div>
<div class="filter-item" style="padding-top: 4.625px; padding-bottom: 4.625px; border-width: 1px; margin: 2px; height: 20px; box-sizing: content-box; width: 344px;">
<input class="filter-item-input" value="Sage Peachtree Premium Accounting 13.0 SR1 (2006)" type="checkbox">
<span class="filter-item-text">Sage Peachtree Premium Accounting 13.0 SR1 (2006)</span>
</div>
<div class="filter-item" style="padding-top: 4.625px; padding-bottom: 4.625px; border-width: 1px; margin: 2px; height: 20px; box-sizing: content-box; width: 344px;">
<input class="filter-item-input" value="Sage Peachtree Premium Accounting 13.0 SR2 (2006)" type="checkbox">
<span class="filter-item-text">Sage Peachtree Premium Accounting 13.0 SR2 (2006)</span>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you mean by ` every time last element is same only data inside element gets refreshed.` ?  could you put the html snippet of that element before and after change ?

Comment: HI Gaurav I have Added Code